# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite rules in web.config does not work

Tags: url-rewriting, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I just moved another site to the server but URL Rewrite rules didn't work. So, I installed URL Rewrite 2.0 from iis.net but no luck.

I can see URL Rewrite icon when I select the site from IIS Manager but there is no record.

I don't want to move rules from web.config to URL Rewrite section one by one.

Here the content of web.config file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ...
        <section name="RewriterConfig" type="URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfigSerializerSectionHandler, URLRewriter" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

    <RewriterConfig>
        <Rules>
            <!-- TR -->
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sayfalar/Kategoriler/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sayfalar/Kategoriler/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sayfalar/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sayfalar/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Kategoriler/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=2&amp;CategoryID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Urunler/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=2&amp;ProductID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Haberler/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=30&amp;NewsID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Tarifler/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=22&amp;RecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sizin-Tarifiniz/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=21&amp;YourRecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=0</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <!-- // TR -->
            <!-- AR -->
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Arabic.aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sfhat/Al-Fiat/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sfhat/Al-Fiat/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sfhat/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Sfhat/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Al-Fiat/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=59&amp;CategoryID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Al-Mntjat/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=59&amp;ProductID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Khbar/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=58&amp;NewsID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Wsfat/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=63&amp;RecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Ldyk-Wşfh/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=62&amp;YourRecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=1</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <!-- // AR -->
            <!-- // ENG -->
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/English.aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Pages/Categories/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Pages/Categories/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Pages/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?ParentRawUrl=$2&amp;RawUrl=$3&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Pages/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Categories/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=111&amp;CategoryID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Product.aspx?ID=111&amp;ProductID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/News/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=30&amp;NewsID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Recipes/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=118&amp;RecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <RewriterRule>
                <LookFor>~/Your-Recipes/(.*)/(.*).aspx</LookFor>
                <SendTo>~/Page.aspx?RawUrl=$2&amp;ID=119&amp;YourRecipeID=$1&amp;Lang=2</SendTo>
            </RewriterRule>
            <!-- // ENG -->
        </Rules>
    </RewriterConfig>
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules are not for the Microsoft URL Rewrite module. By Googling on `RewriterConfig` I found that these rules are possibly for Spring MVC rewrite module.